# how to set div on the body background image

Tags: css, background-image, overlay

![my present design**i have designed a website like this. 
**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OYhu.jpg)
it is working fine for my screen resolution. the bottom div is half way up on the background image and half way down from the background image. my problem is when i test this for higher resolution screen it is not looking the same. the image is moving down. this is my css

```
body
{
    background: #ffffff url(../images/11.jpg) no-repeat center top 0%;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-size: 100% 75%;
    font-family: Arial;
}
```

the bottom div css

```
.banner {
width: 100%;
min-height: 300px;
height: 100%;
background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

how to set this same for all screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

You say the image is moving down, do you mean when you scroll the image moves but you want it static? If so you could add `background-attachment:fixed;` to  the `body`'s CSS.

Comment: What user3634064 says is correct, if the image does not have to be full width it is probably best to apply the background image to a container div and set a `max-width` on it.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the proportion of the image doesn't let the image fit the whole screen.

set the

```
body {
    ...
    width : 100%;
    height : 100%;
}
```